# Mess with data inside class w/ databinding

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

Im trying to edit some data within a class which is linked to with databinding. Here is my class:

```
public class Line
{
    public string Equation { get; set; }
    public int PreviousLine { get; set; }
    public int LineNumber { get; private set; }

    public Line()
    {
        this.LineNumber = (this.PreviousLine + 5);
    }
}
```

however the line number always returns 5, even if previous line is set to 6...

here is how I link to it within my viewmodel:

```
this.Lines.Add(new Line { Equation = "5*2", PreviousLine = 6 });
```

thanks

Comment: Can you show your binding code? It's probably only binding to the first element in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private int _previousLine;
    public int PreviousLine
    {
        get { return _previousLine; }
        set { _previousLine = value;
            Line = _previousLine + 5;
        }
    }
    public int Line { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try declaring it as static.

```
public static int PreviousLine { get; set; }
```